# How can I rearrange my list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have this list,

```
  {{a}, {i1, i2, i3}, {1, 2, 3}}
```

which I want to rearrange to this:

```
  {{1, i1, a}, {2, i2, a}, {3, i3, a}}
```

It is for use with [ListPlot3D[]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot3D.html). How can I do it?

Comment: `Transpose@Reverse[PadRight[#, 3, a] & /@ list]`

Comment: @BobHanlon  That will work on the OP's MWE (at least I assume it's an MWE...), but not on longer examples, e.g., `list={{a}, {i1, i2, i3, i4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}`.

Comment: @theorist - more generally, `Transpose@
 Reverse[PadRight[#, Length[list[[-1]]], list[[1, 1]]] & /@ list]`

Comment: @BobHanlon  Another approach using padding: `ArrayPad[Thread@Reverse@Rest@list, {{0}, {0, 1}}, First@list]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A crappy attempt:

```
{{a}, {i1, i2, i3}, {1, 2, 3}} /. {a_, b_, c_} :> 
   Thread[List[c, b, x]] /. x :> a
```

Comment: Could you please tell me what this symbol ( :> ) is? I couldn't find it

Comment: @DelaramNematollahi See here: [Rule Delayed](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html)

Comment: @Charmbracelet Thank you

Answer (score 8):

```
Thread[{#3,#2,Sequence@@#1}]&@@lst
```

> {{1, i1, a}, {2, i2, a}, {3, i3, a}}

**Slightly shorter**

```
Thread[{#3,#2,First@#1}]&@@lst
```

Answer (score 5):

```
list = {{a}, {i1, i2, i3}, {1, 2, 3}} 
#~Join~First@list& /@Thread@Reverse@Rest@list
```

Answer (score 4):

```
f = Thread @ Reverse @ PadRight[#, Automatic, #] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
lst1 = {{a}, {i1, i2, i3}, {1, 2, 3}};

f @ lst1
```

> ```
>  {{1, i1, a}, {2, i2, a}, {3, i3, a}}
> ```

```
lst2 = {{a}, {i1, i2, i3}, {x, y}, {1, 2, 3, 4}};

f @ lst2
```

> ```
>  {{1, x, i1, a}, {2, y, i2, a}, {3, x, i3, a}, {4, y, i1, a}}
> ```

Comment: I think `Transpose` is a little more natural/accessible here than `Thread`.